# Select NumPy Values Around Index

Tags: python, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

m = 3
x = np.array([1, 0, 0, np.inf, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, np.inf, np.inf, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
y = np.arange(x.shape[0]-m+1)
```

Let's say that where ever there is an `np.inf` in `x`, that index position is called `i`. For each `i`, I want to set the values of `y[i-m+1:i+m] = np.inf`. So, after the replacement, `y` should look like:

```
array([0, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 6, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
```

This should also work when the value of `m` is either increased or decreased.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution I can think of is to use the [np.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) function to dilate a mask. This can be done as follows:

```
mask = np.convolve(x==np.inf, [True]*(m*2-1), mode='same')
y[mask[:-m+1]] = np.inf
```

Comment: Double checking the output does not match, you're missing the intervals -m+1

Comment: I see that I messed up the "m". That moment when maybe test-driven development is better. Seems to be right now @yatu?

Comment: @SholtoArmstrong Is there a way to add some safe guards so that the indices don't exceed those that are available in y. For instance, if x = np.array([1, 0, 0, np.inf, 0, 0, 1]) and m = 3 then this would fail. The expected output would be `[0, inf, inf, inf, 0]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach defineing an integer mask to index `y` and using `broadcasting`:

```
m = 3
x = np.array([1, 0, 0, np.inf, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, np.inf, np.inf, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
y = np.arange(x.shape[0]-m+1).astype(float)
```

---

```
i = np.flatnonzero(x == np.inf)
y[(i + np.arange(-m+1,m)[:,None]).ravel('F')] = np.inf

print(y)
array([ 0., inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,  6., inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       13., 14., 15., 16., 17.])
```

Comment: Is there a way to add some safe guards so that the indices don't exceed those that are available in `y`. For instance, if `x = np.array([1, 0, 0, np.inf, 0, 0, 1])` and `m = 3` then this would fail with `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5`

Answer (score 1):

So you basically have the solution already,

```
import numpy as np
m = 3
x = np.array([1, 0, 0, np.inf, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, np.inf, np.inf, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
y = np.arange(x.shape[0]-m+1)

idx = np.where(x == np.inf)[0] # grabs all i's
for i in idx: # applies the operation you described at each i
    y[(i-m+1):(i+m)] = np.inf # slightly changed indices
```

The only thing I think you have wrong is that I believe it should be from `i-m+1` to `i+m`. Hope that helps!

Comment: You're right. I forgot that the stop range is exclusive rather than inclusive. I've corrected it in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Using [np.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html?highlight=meshgrid#numpy.meshgrid)

```
m = 3
x = np.array([1, 0, 0, np.inf, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, np.inf, np.inf, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) 
y = np.arange(x.shape[0]-m+1, dtype=float)

inf_ndx = np.flatnonzero(np.isinf(x))  # where the infs are
a, b = np.meshgrid(inf_ndx, np.arange(-m+1,m))  # expand the indexes with the ranges
y[a+b] = np.inf  # set all such locations to inf

print(inf_ndx)    
print(a)
print(b)
print(y)
```

produces

```
[ 3  9 10]
[[ 3  9 10]
 [ 3  9 10]
 [ 3  9 10]
 [ 3  9 10]
 [ 3  9 10]]
[[-2 -2 -2]
 [-1 -1 -1]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 1  1  1]
 [ 2  2  2]]
[ 0. inf inf inf inf inf  6. inf inf inf inf inf inf 13. 14. 15. 16. 17.]
```